# What does this variance equation describe? And where does it come from?

Tags: statistics

\begin{eqnarray}
\bar{y^2}=\bar{y}^2+s_{y}^{2}
\end{eqnarray}

where s_{y}^{2} is the variance of y

I have this equation written in my notes but I can't remember how it was derived or where it comes from? Thanks for any help with this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does $\sum (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2 = \sum Y_i^2 - n\bar{Y}^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196925/how-does-sum-y-i-bary2-sum-y-i2-n-bary2)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the definition $S^2 = \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2,$ where $\bar X = \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i,$ then your equation is *exactly* true. However, the usual definition of $S^2$ has $n-1$ in the denominator.

Consider the numerator:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2
= \sum_{i=1}^n [X_i^2 - 2\bar XX_i + \bar X^2]\\
= \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2- 2\bar X\sum_{i=1}^n X_i +n\bar X^2\\
 = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - 2n\bar X^2 + n\bar X^2
=  \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - n\bar X^2.$$

Then $S^2 = \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \bar X^2,$
which you might write as
$S_x^2 = \overline{{X^2}} - \bar{X}^2$ or as
$\overline{{X^2}} = \bar{X}^2+S_x^2.$

*Notes:* (1)  While $S^2 = \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \bar X^2$ is true as a theorem, this relationship
very sensitive to rounding errors, so it must be used with great care in computation---with no rounding
at all until you get the final answer.

(2) For random variables there is a similar
identity:  $Var(X) = E(X^2) - [E(X)]^2.$